# Bootstrap 3.1.1 Page: Hide the URL of links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, printing, responsive-design

I have a Bootstrap 3.1.1 page, that I would like to hide the URL of links when doing a print / print preview. How can I do this?

I want to show the links themselves like "Cart", "My Account", etc etc., but do not want to show the links.

Screenshot of what's occurring:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lQrx.png

Answer (score 13):

```
@media print {
  a[href]:after {
    content: "";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

@iamnotsam is right. I needed to add !important after the content to get it to work.

```
    @media print {
      a[href]:after {
        content: "" !important;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I apologize for not responding in a comment to @iamnotsam... I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: If it's in a later stylesheet that shouldn't be necessary

Answer (score 1):

On my pages, most of the time I like Bootstrap's default behaviour of printing the URL after the anchor tags.  Rather than removing all of the URLs by default, I decided to remove URLs from links with a certain class.

Trying to keep with Bootstrap's class naming scheme, for each link where I did not want to see the URL printed after it, I gave the anchor tag the class `hidden-print-href`.

Then, I added the following lines to my site stylesheet.

```
@media print {
    a.hidden-print-href[href]:after {
        content: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could similarly remove all of the appended URLs by default, then add back the ones you want using a class, say, `visible-print-href`.  You'd need a few more lines of CSS to do that.